# Why is generator not identical to comprehension in 2D comprehension

Tags: julia, for-comprehension, sequence-generators

What is the logic between one generator producing a 1D array and the other a 2D array in the following expressions (version 0.6.2):

```
julia> collect((a,b,c) for (a,b) in ((i,j) for i in 1:2 for j in 3:4), c in 5:6)
8-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 3, 5)
 (1, 4, 5)
 (2, 3, 5)
 (2, 4, 5)
 (1, 3, 6)
 (1, 4, 6)
 (2, 3, 6)
 (2, 4, 6)

julia> collect((a,b,c) for (a,b) in [(i,j) for i in 1:2 for j in 3:4], c in 5:6)
4×2 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64},2}:
 (1, 3, 5)  (1, 3, 6)
 (1, 4, 5)  (1, 4, 6)
 (2, 3, 5)  (2, 3, 6)
 (2, 4, 5)  (2, 4, 6)
```

The only difference is replacing the generator in the first expression with a comprehension in the second expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((i,j) for i in 1:2 for j in 3:4)`
and  `[(i,j) for i in 1:2, j in 3:4]` are parsed to expressions with a final `flatten` operation. The expression `[(i,j) for i in 1:2, j in 3:4]` is collected to a vector giving it `iteratorsize` `HasShape` so it behaves nicely in products.

`Base.iteratorsize(f(i,j) for i in 1:2 for j in 3:4)` in general is `SizeUnknown` <strike>because we do not know the return type of `f`</strike> and operators in products with `SizeUnknown` make the entire product `SizeUnknown` and hence flat when collected.

You might also be looking for

```
julia> collect((a,b,c) for (a,b) in ((i,j) for i in 1:2, j in 3:4), c in 5:6)
2×2×2 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64},3}

julia> collect((a,b,c) for (a,b) in [(i,j) for i in 1:2, j in 3:4], c in 5:6)
2×2×2 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64},3}:
```

(no flatten involved in forming the first generator and everything goes through fine).

Edit: I think now `Base.iteratorsize(f(i,j) for i in 1:2 for j in 3:4)` can be `HasShape`, I'll take a shot at adding that behaviour to `flatten`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Changing `Base.iteratorsize(f(i,j) for i in 1:2 for j in 3:4)` to `HasShape` seems to be right but breaking too. What about `Base.iteratorsize((i,j) for i in 1:2, j in 3:4 if true)` vs `Base.iteratorsize([(i,j) for i in 1:2, j in 3:4 if true])`? BTW difference between these two `Base.iteratorsize( [(i, show(0)) for i in 1:2])
` and `Base.iteratorsize( ((i, show(0)) for i in 1:2))
` is interesting too.

Comment: @Liso and mschauer, it would be nice if collecting a product comprehension would always yield a multidimensional array. There may be issues in making it efficient when some factors have SizeUnknown etc., but the form strongly suggests a certain expected result and it would be nice to meet expectations.  For the vector output a flatten comprehension is still available.

Comment: Edit: I looked into this, it will not be easy to implement. The expression `((i,j) for i in 1:2 for j in 3:4)` is roughly equivalent to 
`flatten((j -> (i,j) for j in 3:4)(j) for i in 1:2)`, and there is no way for flatten to look into the anonymous function to figure out the `length` of its return value ahead of collecting.